# Netstat failed to show result

Tags: windows, windows-10, netstat

I am trying to run an application on port 8080 but I received a message that says "Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use." I tried to access localhost:8080 on my browser and it says "unable to connect". I searched on how to handle this problem and it was to kill whatever activity is going on in port 8080. It didn't work. I tried the command netstat -a -n -o | find "8080" and netstat -ano | findstr :, but it didn't produce any results. I even tried to run as administrator but it still wouldn't show any results. According to the solutions that I found, I expect to find something along the lines of TCP and LISTENING. I accessed localhost:8080 a couple of days back and it was fine. Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

[picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykg6r.jpg)

The only recent changes I made was to enable VMX on my laptop a few days ago. Other than that, I did not change nor configure any settings whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Simply running "netstat -ab" will display all ports taken. Try to run it and see which process is using port 8080. It always lists all ports taken.